# Issue with group by and order by with two foriegn key in same table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like users,messages

```
Users Table
id,uname,email,profile_pic.....

messages Table
id,from_id,to_id,message,created_at
```

here from_id and to_id is foreign key for users table id.

i want to get latest messaged user with message. i have tried like this

```
SELECT 
`u`.`firstname`,
`u`.`lastname`,
`u`.`profile_photo`,
`u`.`id`,
`u2`.`firstname`,
`u2`.`lastname`,
`u2`.`profile_photo`,
`u2`.`id`,
`message`,
`messages`.`created_at`,
`messages`.`from_id`,
`messages`.`to_id`,
`messages`.`id` AS `mid`
FROM
`messages`
INNER JOIN
`users` AS `u` ON `u`.`id` = `messages`.`from_id`
INNER JOIN
`users` AS `u2` ON `u2`.`id` = `messages`.`to_id`
WHERE
(from_id = 26 OR to_id = 26)
GROUP BY
`u`.`id`,
`u2`.`id`
ORDER BY
`messages`.`id` DESC
```

but i got first message only.But i need to get  --order by messages.id descending

Sample data

```
   User table
id   | firstname | email           | mobile
---------------------------------------------
1    | ram       | ram@gmail.com   | 9876543210
----------------------------------------------
2    | jack      | jack@gmail.com  | 8876543216
----------------------------------------------
3    | rams      | rams@gmail.com  | 7876543215
----------------------------------------------
4    | devid     | devid@gmail.com | 9876543220
----------------------------------------------
5    | sri       | sri@gmail.com   | 8876543212
----------------------------------------------
```

messages table

```
id | from_id  | to_id | message            | created_at
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |   1      |    2  |  how r u           | 2017-02-03
-------------------------------------------------------  
2  |   2      |    1  |  fine              | 2017-02-03
-------------------------------------------------------
3  |   2      |    3  |  hi                | 2017-02-03
-------------------------------------------------------
4  |   3      |    2  |  hello             | 2017-02-03
-------------------------------------------------------
5  |   1      |    2  |  hello how are you | 2017-02-03 
-------------------------------------------------------
6  |   3      |    1  |  good night        | 2017-02-03 
-------------------------------------------------------
8  |   1      |    3  |  good night rams   | 2017-02-03 
-------------------------------------------------------
7  |   3      |    1  |  hello ram         | 2017-02-03 
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected output:

```
firstname | message           | mid | uid
-----------------------------------------
rams      | hello ram         | 7   | 3
-----------------------------------------
jack      | hello how are you | 5   | 2
-----------------------------------------
```

This is the chat application we assume login user is ram (id=1) from user table

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output in your question.

Comment: add after where condition  **having max(`messages`.`created_at`)**

Comment: provide table data and explain ....what you want

Comment: i have provided sample data

Comment: Any one please help this issue